# Unresolvable error with Parse "Get Data In Background With Block"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I don't know if this is user error or due to the Xcode and Swift updates. I'm pulling image files off of Parse and no matter how I tweak the syntax I get a persistent error of:

> swift:64:23: Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' with an
>   argument list of type '((NSData!, NSError?) -> Void)

My code is:

```
func callData() {

    var imageQuery = PFObject(className: "QuestionMaster")
    let iconImageFile = imageQuery["questionImage"] as! PFFile!
    iconImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            self.icon1 = UIImage(data: imageData[0])
            self.icon2 = UIImage(data: imageData[1])
            self.icon3 = UIImage(data: imageData[2])
            self.icon4 = UIImage(data: imageData[3])
            self.icon5 = UIImage(data: imageData[4])
            self.icon6 = UIImage(data: imageData[5])
            self.icon7 = UIImage(data: imageData[6])
            self.icon8 = UIImage(data: imageData[7])
            self.icon9 = UIImage(data: imageData[8])
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Something went wrong.")
        }
```

I've been working straight from the Parse docs. I have also tried:

```
iconImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(imageQuery, block: {
            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

And I've exchanged `!` and `?` to no avail. The same things happens elsewhere in my code with `findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due the changes in swift 1.2. Parse should have already provided a version of their framework that fixes this. Download it from their website.

**Edit**

Also, don't forget to unwrap the imageData value with `if let`

The following code works for me on the lastest Parse framework version using swift 1.2

```
imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if let imageData = imageData where error == nil
    {
        self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time.